# Creating a list of docs that contains same name

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating a tool that is supposed to concatenate docs that contain the same name.

example: C_BA_20000_1.pdf and C_BA_20000_2.pdf
These files should be grouped in one list.
That tool runs on a directory lets say

```
//directory of pdf files
  DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\derp\Desktop");

  FileInfo[] fileInfos = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.pdf");
```

foreach (FileInfo info in fileInfos)

I want to create an ArrayList that contains filenames of the same name

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
 list.Add(info.FullName);
```

and then have a list that contains all the ArrayLists of similar docs.

```
 List<ArrayList> bigList = new List<ArrayList>();
```

So my question, how can I group files that contains same name and put them in the same list.

**EDIT:**
Files have the same pattern in their names AB_CDEFG_i
where i is a number and can be from 1-n. Files with the same name should have only different number at the end.

> AB_CDEFG_1
>
> AB_CDEFG_2
>
> HI_JKLM_1

Output should be:

List 1:  AB_CDEFG_1 and AB_CDEFG_2

List 2:  HI_JKLM_1

Comment: Do you mean `C_BA_20000_1` and `C_BA_20000_2` should be in the same list because they start with `C_BA_20000_`

Comment: @raym0nd how do you determine that files have same name?

Comment: If they both start with C are they the same?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen someone create a `List<ArrayList>` before.

Comment: @all please check question again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create method which extracts 'same' part of file name. E.g.

```
public string GetRawName(string fileName)
{
    int index = fileName.LastIndexOf("_");
    return fileName.Substring(0, index);
}
```

And use this method for grouping:

```
var bigList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\derp\Desktop", "*.pdf")
                       .GroupBy(file => GetRawName(file))
                       .Select(g => g.ToList())
                       .ToList();
```

This will return `List<List<string>>` (without `ArrayList`).

**UPDATE** Here is regular expression, which will work with all kind of files, whether they have number at the end, or not

```
public string GetRawName(string file)
{
    string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
    return Regex.Replace(name, @"(_\d+)?$", "")
}
```

Grouping:

```
var bigList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\derp\Desktop", "*.pdf")
                       .GroupBy(GetRawName)
                       .Select(g => g.ToList())
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: +1 for `Directory.EnumerateFiles` you learn something new everyday ! ha :)

Comment: @raym0nd I've added update, which use regular expression to extract raw file name

Comment: @raym0nd verify last update with `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` I got that extension should be removed for regex, but it was after I posted regex sample :)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that your question doesnt identify what "same name" means. This is a typical solution.

```
fileInfos.GroupBy ( f => f.FullName )
         .Select( grp =>  grp.ToList()  ).ToList();
```

Comment: fileInfos.GroupBy  doesn't exist :s

Comment: then you have to include `using System.Linq;` at the top.

Comment: but again this will compare filenames, it's clear you want some sort of logic there so you have to figure how you want to compare your filenames.

Comment: @StanR. just add key selector, and return file name instead of whole FileInfo, and this also will be correct solution :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky sure, i wrote this before he changed his question...and then i stopped following :) i dont mind you can have all the glory !!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the difficulty is in deciding which files are the same.

```
static string KeyFromFileName(string file)
{
   // Convert from "C_BA_20000_2" to "C_BA_20000"
   return file.Substring(0, file.LastIndexOf("_"));

   // Note: This assumes there is an _ in the filename.
}
```

Then you can use this LINQ to build a list of fileSets.

```
using System.Linq; // Near top of file


var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\derp\Desktop", "*.pdf")

var fileSets = files
   .Select(file => file.FullName)
   .GroupBy(KeyFromFileName)
   .Select(g => new {g.Key, Files = g.ToList()}
   .ToList();
```

Comment: +1 for `GroupBy(KeyFromFileName)` - better way to call key parser method. But OP wanted list of file names..

Answer (score 0):

This will get you a list of lists... also won't throw an exception if a file doesn't contain the underscore, etc.

```
private string GetKey(FileInfo fi)
{
    var index = fi.Name.LastIndexOf('_');
    return index == -1 ? Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name) 
                       : fi.Name.Substring(0, index);
}

var bigList = fileInfos.GroupBy(GetKey)
             .Select(x => x.ToList())
             .ToList();
```